# Matlab and shifted QR algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sorting, math

This is a problem concerning with matlab and shifted QR algorithm. I know that I should have posted this question in stackoverflow, but it seems that I need to wait another 2 days to post next question. I really appreciate it if someone could help me understand the error of this code. I want to use the method to find the approximate eigenvalues of the matrix and also the norm of the error.

But when I run this code, it shows that

> Error in shiftedqr (line 27) while max(abs(a(n,1:n-1)))>tol && kount

```
%Inputs:
% n = size
% A is a n x n matrix
% a = how much matrix A is wanted to be shifted
% kounttol is the number of iterations
% d is the first number needed to form matrix T
% u is the second number needed to form matrix T
% tol is the the tolerance for the residual, i.e. your iteration
% should stop once the number of iteration is smaller than kounttol
% e is the vector of eigenvalues of matrix A
% m is the number of iterations k actually done

function lam=shiftedqr(n ,a, kounttol, d, u)
tol = 0.1e-08;
m = max([d, u, 1]);
v = ones(1, n-1);
D1 = diag(v,1);
N = D1;
T = (d*eye(n) + u*N)/m;
A = T + T';
e = eig (A);


while n>1
    kount=0;
    while max(abs(a(n,1:n-1)))>tol && kount<kounttol
        kount=kount+1;    
        mu=a(n,n);         
        [q,r]=qr(a-mu*eye(n));
    a=r*q+mu*eye(n);
    end
end
if kount<kounttol
    lam(n)=a(n,n);
n=n-1;
a=a(1:n,1:n);
else
end 
if n>0;lam(1)=a(1,1);end 

B = sort(e);
C = sort(lam(n));
error = norm(B-C);
disp(error);
```

Comment: What is the rest of the error message? Matlab gives more details than just "Error on line"

Answer (score 0):

Looks lite you mixed `a` with `A`.

According to your comment `a = how much matrix A is wanted to be shifted`, `a` is scalar (not a matrix).

When trying to execute your code, I am getting the error message:

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
> Error in shiftedqr (line 27) while max(abs(a(n,1:n-1)))>tol && kount

It looks like your implementation has multiple problems.
You should learn how to use the debugger - go step by step through your code, and watch the values of each variable in the workspace pane.
You can also type the variable in the command window, and you can also modify values using command window (when it helps debugging).

Note: For easier debugging, I modified the function into a script.
Remember to change it back to a function, after fixing the code.

I modified your code, to be "executable", but it still needs fixing:

```
%For debugging, set original function parameters here (should be removed).
%Set some arbitary values (just for executing the code once)
n = 3;
a = 1;
kounttol = 2;
d = 1;
u = 2;

%Remove commended line, after fixing all problems
%function lam=shiftedqr(n ,a, kounttol, d, u)
tol = 0.1e-08;
m = max([d, u, 1]);
v = ones(1, n-1);
D1 = diag(v,1);
N = D1;
T = (d*eye(n) + u*N)/m;
A = T + T';
e = eig (A);

lam = zeros(1, n); %Initialize lam to zeros.

while n>1
    kount=0;
    while max(abs(A(n,1:n-1)))>tol && kount<kounttol
        kount=kount+1;    
        mu=A(n,n);         
        [q,r]=qr(a-mu*eye(n));
        A=r*q+mu*eye(n);
    end

    if kount<=kounttol
        lam(n)=A(n,n);
        n=n-1;
        A=A(1:n,1:n);
    end

    if n>0;lam(1)=A(1,1);end 
end

B = sort(e);
C = sort(lam(n));
error = norm(B-C);
disp(error);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much! I wanted to vote up, but I don't have enough reputations. Could you please elaborate your idea? Do you mean that I need to set original parameters? Why is that helpful? I am very new to coding, thank you again!

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again, but I changed the number of kounttol, but the answer remains the same.. does that mean this code is wrong?

Comment: **1.** What answer remains the same? are you still getting an the error message? **2.** If you are getting an error, is it "`Index exceeds matrix dimensions`." or other error? **3.** What are the actual values you are using for input parameters `n`, `a`, `kounttol`, `d`, `u`? **4.** I tried to teach you how to debug you code. Shortcut keys: use **F10** for executing single step, use **F12** to place a breakpoint.

Comment: Hi! Yea! Thank you very much!